# window.open compatible for all browsers?

Tags: javascript

I want to open a window from PHP. As it's impossible to do with PHP, I send to Javascript the following command:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">window.open("/help/help_central.php","my window", "height=200, width=200, top=100, left=500, menubar=0, toolbar=0, location=0, status=0");</script>';
```

With FF 11.0 only height,width,top,left can be changed (for me !). I tried with yes/no but same effect.
Do you know a solution compatible for ALL common browsers (FF,IE,Safari,Chrome,Opera) ?

Comment: [QuirksMode - Popups](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html)

Comment: try with `"mywindow"` without space on the name not `"my window"`

Comment: Pop up blockers will block this pop up in the wild.

Comment: mywindow or my windows: that doesn't change !

Comment: but QuirksMode gives answer to my questions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally yes it works everywhere however not all the features are supported by all browsers.

This article is a good read to find out what works and what doesn't depending on the browsers.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

Another good reference is

http://www.gtalbot.org/BugzillaSection/Bug195867GDR_WindowOpen.html

You might want to consider using a modal window instead as that you will manage to make work everywhere and popup might also get blocked by browsers plugin security settings when a modal wont.

Comment: Second link is broken.